# Event to bind a gridview inside another gridview

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview control inside another gridview control. When I click on the edit button the second gridview inside the 1st one should bind with a data source.

I am using a  `SqlDataSource` and configured it. In which event of the gridview do I need to write the code for binding the records?

I am new to .net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `RowCommand Event`

```
 protected void SecondGrid_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "Edit")
        {
           FirstGrid.DataBind()
        }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to write your data binding logic in Parent grid's OnEditCommand event. Further details can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datagrid.oneditcommand.aspx)